# How to download Ubuntu Touch for a Samsung J3 J320F

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samsung

I want to download Ubuntu Touch on to a Samsung J320F.

The download fails and the Ubuntu installer says that this device is not available.

I want help or a ROM for download.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, your phone is not (yet) supported.

Currently, only four Samsung devices are:

> Samsung S3 Neo+ (GT-I9301I)
>
> Samsung Galaxy S7 (herolte)
>
> Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (910F, 910P, 910T)
>
> Samsung Galaxy S5

See the full list on [Ubuntu Touch - Find your device](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/).

---

However, maybe you could help and contribute towards porting the code to your device:

> To create a port, having some programming skills will come in handy, especially if you are familiar with C / C++. But you can pick up skills as you go. Also, you should familiarize yourself with git and setup a github/gitlab account. Follow the steps as described in our [porting guide](https://docs.ubports.com/en/latest/porting/). It will help you and others if you start documenting your steps to further improve documentation.